How to force a bounded relationship to "become redundant" or "not needed"?
As an engineer who is currently working with some optimization problem I am currently running into a difficult reformulation problem. Here $a$ is a binary decision variable, $\phi \in [0,1]$ and $d$ are just two decision variables. In addition to that, $B$ and $C$ are just two positive numbers that describe the operational characteristic of the system and they are not decision variables.
And hence, my constraint system for situation 1 ($a=1$) is as follows:
$\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{a = 1 \Rightarrow \frac{B}{\phi } \le d \le C}&{\left( {c1} \right)}\\
{\phi  \le a}&{\left( {c2} \right)}\\
{0 \le \phi  \le 1}&{\left( {c3} \right)}\\
{d \ge 0}&{\left( {c4} \right)}
\end{array}} \right.$
In the future, I am not sure if constraint $c_2$ should be a hard constraint or soft constraint but there is still some room for compromise because the spec is not clear at this point. For now, let temporarily consider $c_2$ to be a hard constraint.
For this system it is quite easy to construct a big M formulation when $a=1$ for constraint $c_1$ as follows: $\frac{B}{\phi } - M\left( {1 - a} \right) \le d \le C + M\left( {1 - a} \right)$
However for the case of $a=0$ (situation 2), constraint $c_2$ ruining the mathematical formulation. Particularly, $a = 0 \Rightarrow \phi  = 0$ which leads to an infeasible (division by zero) constraint $\underbrace {\frac{B}{\phi }}_{ + \infty } - \underbrace {M\left( {1 - a} \right)}_{{\rm{finite}}} \le d \le \underbrace C_{{\rm{finite}}} + \underbrace {M\left( {1 - a} \right)}_{{\rm{finite}}}$.
Therefore, my question is "Given that $c_2$ is a hard constraint, is there any way to construct a formulation such that when $a=0$ the bounded relationship ${\frac{B}{\phi } \le d \le C}$ become redundant or not needed or maybe to turn ${\frac{B}{\phi } \le d \le C}$ into a soft constraint when $a=0$ ?"
P/S: Note that in the future, $c_2$ may become a soft constraint after some compromise between the engineers.

Your big-M formulation is not linear (because of $B/\phi$)

Within the context of whatever engineering problem you are addressing, does $a=0$ mean that $d$ is free to take on any nonnegative value, no matter how large or small?

Not linear is ok. But at least it is convex in some sense. Well within my context when $a=0$ then $d$ should take a small non-negative value. But If you are providing a case where $d$ is large then I am willing to listen to your advice !

@TuongNguyenMinh, for simplicity you can drop $d \leq C$ as a bound constraint. Now and if at the moment the non-linearity does not matter, why not try $((a=1) \implies (B \leq d \phi))$ that yields $(B \leq d \phi + M(1-a))$. By that if $a = 0$ then $\phi$ can be zero without complaint of any division by zero.

Well sadly it is very difficult to drop the upper bound constraint

@TuongNguyenMinh, if you need to have the bound constraint, the situation is very similar to $(a=1) \implies ((B \leq d \phi) \land (d \leq C))$. It can be linearized by defining the auxiliary binary variables. Do you try that?
